# Sorting of Mutlidimensinal Array

Tags: php, arrays, sorting

I have following array

```
    Array(
           [0]= Array
               ( 
              [name]=>room
             other paramters

            )
       [1]=Array (
         [name]=>abc
        and so on

    )

   )
```

I want to sort by name

i tried to use usort. but i am not able to get proper results

```
usort($array,'sort_by_name');
function sort_by_name($a,$b) {
 return $a- $b;
}
```

Any idea?

Thanks

Comment: `usort()` is probably not what you need, and without showing the rest of the code we can only assume you're not using it correctly. Try `ksort()`.

Comment: @slime `ksort` would sort by the key, not the value. As in the `0` and `1`. @OP `usort` is correct and in your compare function just use something like `return strcasecmp($a['name'], $b['name']);` in your compare function. php already has a string comparison function that returns the proper values, you just need to reference the key.

Comment: `function sort_by_name($a,$b) {
 return strcmp($a['name'], $b['name']);
}` perhaps?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use [`array_multisort`](http://docs.php.net/manual/en/function.array-multisort.php). For your particular example, where `$array` is the initial array:

```
$names = array();
foreach ($array as $key => $row)
{
    $names[$key] = $row['name'];
}
array_multisort($names, SORT_ASC, $array);
```

Answer (score 0):

This method allows you to sort data in a direction, specify a field, and say if the field is a date.

```
private function multiSort($data, $sortDirection, $field, $isDate) {
if (empty($data) || !is_array($data) || count($data) < 2) {
    return $data;
}

$parts = explode("/", $field);
foreach ($data as $key => $row) {
    $temp = &$row;
    foreach ($parts as $key2) {
        $temp = &$temp[$key2];
    }
    $orderByDate[$key] = ($isDate ? strtotime($temp) : $temp);
}
unset($temp);
unset($parts);

if ($sortDirection == "SORT_DESC") {
    array_multisort($orderByDate, SORT_DESC, $data);
} else {
    array_multisort($orderByDate, SORT_ASC, $data);
}
unset($orderByDate);
return $data;
}
```

This blog post should be helpful: [Multisort by key](http://blog.sixthpoint.com/multisort-by-key/)